# how to make a patch request in java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, http, curl

I tried to convert the following patch request which **partially updates a metadata**:

```
curl -v -X PATCH --data '{"description": "a test file",
"name":"fooNew.jpg", "labels":["PHOTO", "test"]}'
https://cdws.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/drive/v1/nodes/11jqgRBmPBKzlY6_bu9Pew
--header 'Authorization: Bearer
Atza|IQEBLjAsAhQ5zx7pKp9PCgCy6T1JkQjHHOEzpwIUQM'
```

into the following Java code:

```
BasicCookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
        CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom()
                .setDefaultCookieStore(cookieStore)
                .build();


           StringBody metadata = new StringBody("{\"description\":"+"new desciption"+", \"name\":"+"new name"+",\"labels\":[\"PHOTO\", \"test\"]}", ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON);
           
           HttpEntity reqEntity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create()
                   .addPart("metadata", metadata)
                   .build();
        
        
        CloseableHttpResponse response2 = null;
        try {
            
            HttpPatch login = new HttpPatch("https://cdws.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/drive/v1/nodes/11jqgRBmPBKzlY6_bu9Pew");
            
            login.addHeader("Host", "content-na.drive.amazonaws.com");
            login.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);

            login.setEntity(reqEntity);
            
            
            response2 = httpclient.execute(login);

            HttpEntity entity = response2.getEntity();


            InputStream in =   entity.getContent();
            StringBuilder sb = Utils.parseInputStream(in);
            System.out.println(sb);
            EntityUtils.consume(entity);
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(sb.toString());

            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.print(e.getMessage() );
        }
```

The Java code is used to partially update a metadata (see [reference](https://developer.amazon.com/public/apis/experience/cloud-drive/content/nodes)). It does not throw an Exception and returns a blank response instead of the response same as the reference above.

Would you give me a hint about how to update the Java code to have the same behavior like the cURL request?

Comment: I hope the posted token is invalid..

Comment: The posted token is from the documentation of amazon cloud drive api not from my project.